# Mono Cecil add missing assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, mono.cecil

For some reason when I try to load some assembly and analyze it, I'm getting error `Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly...`

I don't really care about why this exception throw, I know where is the missing assembly.

There is a way to some something like `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event but for Mono.Cecil?
I can manually load the missing assembly but I don't know how.
So, how can I load an assembly for Mono.Cecil?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently Mono.Cecil support that.
When you load the Assembly with `AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly` inside the `ReadParameters` you can change the `AssemblyResolver` property to your resolver.

To create a resolver just inherit from `BaseAssemblyResolver` like:

```
private class CustomResolver : BaseAssemblyResolver
{
    private DefaultAssemblyResolver _defaultResolver;

    public CustomResolver()
    {
        _defaultResolver = new DefaultAssemblyResolver();
    }

    public override AssemblyDefinition Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name)
    {
        AssemblyDefinition assembly;
        try
        {
            assembly = _defaultResolver.Resolve(name);
        }
        catch (AssemblyResolutionException ex)
        {
             assembly = ...; // Your resolve logic   
        }
        return assembly;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was missing, while working on a .NET Core 3.1 project.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator -Version 4.0.1
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator/

Comment: Yep, this did it for me. I created a new ASP.NET Core 3.1 Azure Functions project. This was my first error. Adding the package fixed it for me. Thank you!